# Problem with Installation of Microsoft VSCode

Tags: software-installation, anaconda, visual-studio-code

I was trying to install Anaconda 3 in Ubuntu 18.10. At one point the terminal prompted me to install Microsoft VSCode. When I proceeded, the terminal informed me that there is an issue with the internet connectivity. Here's a screenshot of the terminal:

[image: Please make sure you are connected to the internet! Check /home/omehoque/anaconda3/vscode_inst.py.log for more info Do you wish to retry?]

I retried, but it didn't work. How can I resolve the issue?

**Edit:**
The `vscode_inst.py.log` has the following information:

```
ERROR:vscode_inst:haveInternet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omehoque/anaconda3/pkgs/vscode_inst.py", line 143, in haveInternet
    assert r.status_code == 200
AssertionError
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I did. I installed anaconda navigator and from there I installed the VSCode.

Comment: Would you mind posting your comment saying how you solved it as an answer below?

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd install [codium from snap](https://snapcraft.io/codium). Codium basically is VSCode without Microsoft Telemetry.